# Rails where two tables have the same data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a table in my view and populate it on some conditions.

I have two tables, Both have two columns inside, One columns called `event_url` and the other is `gmiurl`. The table with gmiurl inside is called `GMITable` and the other is called `newevent`

Basically i want to show everything inside the `GMITable` unless the column `event_url` has a url inside that matches to any of the urls inside `gmiurls` inside the `GMITable`

I dont have anycode for this apart from this at the moment

```
@GMI = GMITable.all
```

Comment: How familiar are you with the SQL JOIN syntax?

Comment: Not very haha! Im sure theres some way to do it inside rails

Comment: SQL and Rails are not mutually exclusive. There will be a day where you have to write some SQL fragment, even if you use ActiveRecord.

Comment: I've only done a bit of sql, I've not done much in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the result by using a LEFT OUTER JOIN from Table A to Table B, as described in [this visual explanation](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Specifically, what you want is:

> To produce the set of records only in Table A, but not in Table B, we perform the same left outer join, then exclude the records we don't want from the right side via a where clause.

In your question is not clear how the tables are called, and how they relate each other. However, to achieve the result simply perform a join between the tables using the ActiveRecord `join` method

```
TableA.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB on TableA.field = TableB.field')
```

and select only the items where(`TableB.id IS NULL`).

You'll have to adapt the example to your needs.